# How to solve Android problem for printing over CUPS?

Tags: android, linux, cups

I don't know if this is the right place to ask these kind of questions, but I know no better platform than this one. Anyway, it's related to networking and Linux.

I have a very old printer in my house (HP LaserJet P2015 Series). I also have a RPi 4 connected to my WiFi. I wanted to make that beforementioned printer capable to print over WiFI. I installed CUPS on RPi. I added printer on CUPS web-interface. Now, this is where I get kind off confused. I go to my laptop, open up some random document on Word, and press CTRL+P to print it. Word finds the printer, and I can with ease print over my laptop (If it's worth something Word displays printer like this: *HP LaserJer P2015@raspberrypi*). When I go to my phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 10, Android 11) and try to print something of off it, phone won't even find it. I tried adding the printer manually, same problem. For troubleshooting, my dad tries the same(Realme X2, Android 11), same problem. Mum's phone(Samsung Galaxy A70), same problem. Every other laptop or tablet in the house finds the printer without problem. Just Android devices can't. I searched other forums, but no one seemed to have this kind of a problem.

Does anyone know the solution? Has this happened to anyone before?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programing questions. For general/power users of Android see [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) and look at [How to print to CUPS (running on another computer in the LAN)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43774/3573) and specifically [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201097/3573).